# DataGridView in child form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a base windows form containing a DataGridView. The DataGridView has the modifier set to Protected.

When creating a descendant form the DataGridView properties cannot be changed. They are greyed out. The events are also not editable through the Properties panel. This would all be in the Designview.

You can however add an event handler to, for example, DoubleClick from inseide the code editor.

Why can this not be done from inside the designer?

I have other controls on the base form also set to Protected which can be altered from Design view in the child form.

Comment: Sounds weird. My guess is you are wrong somehow. But. How could we know?

Comment: All of the other controls on the base form are protected and they can be modified in design mode on the child form.

Answer (score 0):

To modify a control from baseform in inherited forms or usercontrols we should change controls acces modifier property to 'Protected' or 'Public'.

MSDN - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3246a701-cc50-4109-b981-3eea04dacdeb/question-inherited-form-with-control?forum=csharpgeneral

DevExpress - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A679

Comment: Yes I did, and you?

Comment: OP's last sentence claims that other protected and inherited controls can be modified. So either your answer is wrong or (more likely) the question.

Comment: There are several controls as StatusStrip, GridView and ToolStrip we cant modify without changing acces modifier

Comment: The DataGridView is set to protected in the base form